# Checking that a function is in Hardy-2 space of the unit disc around the origin

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, hardy-spaces

I want to check that the function $f(s) = \frac{1}{(s-1)^{0.3}}$ is in $H^2(\mathcal{D(0,1)})$ which is a vector space of holomorphic functions that satisfy
$$
\sup _{0 \leqslant r<1}\left(\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi}\left|f\left(r e^{i \theta}\right)\right|^2 \mathrm{~d} \theta\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}<\infty
$$
So, first I want to evaluate the integral inside the supremum as a function of r:
$\int_0^{2 \pi}\left|f\left(r e^{i \theta}\right)\right|^2 \mathrm{~d} \theta$:
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi}\left|f\left(r e^{i \theta}\right)\right|^2 \mathrm{~d} \theta = \int_0^{2 \pi}\frac{1}{(r e^{i \theta} - 1)^{0.3}}\overline{\frac{1}{(r e^{i \theta} - 1)^{0.3}}} \mathrm{~d} \theta = \int_0^{2 \pi}\frac{1}{(r^2 -2r\cos(\theta) + 1)^{0.3}} \mathrm{~d} \theta 
$$
So it boils down to evaluating the last integral. This is where I'm stuck. Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question? And why did you ignore my edits to your formula previously? Pertaining to this problem, if you only want to prove boundedness that is easier than computing the integral.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I deleted it because I phrased it poorly and it derailed the conversation. I didn't ignore your edits. In fact, I agree with them. 
If you have suggestions for boundedness, please elaborate :)

Comment: The integral is sandwiched between $\frac{2\pi}{(1+r)^{0.6}}$ and $\frac{2\pi}{(1-r)^{0.6}}$ but I can see that doesn't solve your sup problem. I will think about it more.

Comment: @FShrike if you're curious theorems and tricks exist in complex analysis to handle problems like these, even though they are not standard introductory curriculum like Cauchy-Goursat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about it more. Consider the equivalent recast of the integral

$$I = \oint\limits_{\partial D(0,r)}\frac{|dz|}{|z-1|^{0.6}} = \oint\limits_{\partial D(-1,r)} \frac{|dz|}{|z|^{0.6}}$$

By using

$$|dz| = \frac{1+\bar{z}}{ir}dz$$

and the formula

$$\oint_{\partial\Omega}f\:dz = 2i \iint\limits_{\Omega}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}\:dx\wedge dy$$

we get that

$$I = \frac{2}{r}\iint\limits_{D(-1,r)}\frac{dx\wedge dy}{|z|^{0.6}}\left(0.7 - \frac{0.3}{\bar{z}}\right)$$

Converting to polar coordinates (and subtracting $\pi$ from the angular bounds), the integral is

$$I = \frac{2}{r}\int_{-\sin^{-1}r}^{\sin^{-1}r}\int_{\cos\phi-\sqrt{r^2-\sin^2\phi}}^{\cos\phi+\sqrt{r^2-\sin^2\phi}}s^{0.4}\:ds\:d\phi\left(0.7 + \frac{0.3e^{-i\phi}}{s}\right)$$

$$= \frac{1}{r}\int_{0}^{\sin^{-1}r}d\phi \:\Bigr[s^{0.4}(2s+3\cos\phi)\Bigr]_{\cos\phi-\sqrt{r^2-\sin^2\phi}}^{\cos\phi+\sqrt{r^2-\sin^2\phi}}$$

where we utilized even and odd symmetry to simplify the integral as well. The expression from here is not unbounded anywhere on $r\in(0,1)$ as can be verified by using the substitution $\phi = r\theta$:

$$\lim_{r\to 0}I(r) = \lim_{r\to 0}\int_0^{\frac{\sin^{-1}r}{r}}d\theta\:\Bigr[s^{0.4}(2s+3\cos r\theta)\Bigr]_{\cos r\theta-\sqrt{r^2-\sin^2r \theta}}^{\cos r\theta+\sqrt{r^2-\sin^2r\theta}} = \int_0^1 d\theta \cdot [0] = 0$$

I will leave finding the true sup to you, though I suspect it occurs at $r = 1$:

$$I(1) = 7\cdot 2^{0.4}\cdot\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta\:(\cos\theta)^{1.4} \leq \frac{7\pi}{2^{0.6}}$$